# Single endpoint for Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

So, We have created a elasticsearch cluster ourselves using EC2 instances. The cluster works perfectly fine.

We have a total of 3 nodes of which 1 is master, 1 is data node and 1 is master + data node.

So currently, Route53 points to the only master node. What happens when the master node fails for some reason? How do i reroute it to the second master node until the failed node is back in place?

Need some inputs here. How is this achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any programming language in front? If so you can use the elasticsearh library for that programming language can handle that for you and you just have to add all your addresses while creating the client. When you refer to the client it will use the master node for querying . So even if one fails the other server will become master and your client will refer to the new master.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, We are not using any library at the front. We are using Django Framework. We directly query the endpoint.

Comment: Add all your hosts like this .     es = Elasticsearch([
    {'host': 'localhost'},
    {'host': 'othernode'}
]) in your python code using elasticsearch python library.     http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch

Comment: Thanks for your response. We definitely would need to make some changes on them before we can directly start using the elasticsearch-py library. However, definitely helpful on knowing them.